# The second derivative of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**STATEMENT:** Let $f:S\rightarrow S$ be a holomorphic function defined on the unit open square centered at 0. If $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$ what is $f''(0)$?

**QUESTION:** Can someone nudge me in the right direction. I tried taylor expanding $f$ and using Cauchy's inequality for complex functions, but I can't seem to derive an answer for $f''$ evaluated at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi \colon \mathbb{D} \to S$ be the biholomorphic mapping with $\varphi(0) = 0$ and $\varphi'(0) > 0$. Consider the map

$$\varphi^{-1} \circ f \circ \varphi.$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks.